# Роутинг в yii2 не работает action с параметром

Tags: php, yii2

Правила для urlManager

```
 '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
 '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
 '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

Если открываю

```
/controller/id - все ок
/controller/action - все ок
/controller/action/id - выдает 404.
```

Не могу понять никак в чем дело...

Comment: в последнем примере вы так и пишете `id`? или передаете число?

Comment: Число передаю конечно)

Comment: Может последние два правила местами поменять?

Comment: Тоже такая мыль была. Не помогло...

Comment: в дебаг панели на вкладке `Router`(в левом меню панели самая нижняя) что показывается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось проблема в разрешенных символах для action

Это работает:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:[\wd-]+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй так

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```